# orthogonal polynomials and quadrature formulae

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

is it true  that for every set of orthogonal polynomials

$$ \int_{a}^{b} w(x)P_{n}(x)P_{m}(y) =a_{m,n}\delta _{m}^{n}$$

with respect a measure $ w(x)$ can we always find a quadrature formula for integrals in the form

$$ \int_{a}^{b}dx w(x)f(x) \approx \sum_{n} c_{n}f(x_{n}) $$

for the zeros of the orthogonal polynomials $ P_{n}(x_{n})=0 $

another question, let us supoose (in the sense of approximation theory that

$$ LIm_{n\to \infty} P_{2n}(x)= g(x) $$ 
for some function $ g(x) $

if this were true would be also true that the rooth of polynomials would tend to thre roots of $ g(x)$ ?? for big $ n\to 0 $

Comment: You can always find a quadrature formula on any set of points, it's just that with orthogonal polynomials, it's optimal (with respect to the chosen weight function) because the error is orthogonal to the approximation.

Comment: OK thanks good point